# Is it possible to split integer such as "12.13" to 12 and 13?

Tags: javascript

I am new in Javascript and I don't know much about the js programming. I am thinking of separate 12.13 into two-part 12 and 13 from the dot in javascript.

I found on the website separate string into two-part but I don't know how to do with the integer.
    For example,

```
var i = "12.13"
var t = i.split("");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the given number is already a string, then you can directly split it using `.split()` otherwise, convert the number to a string using `.toString()` then `.split()` it.

`String#split` accepts a `separator` as its first parameter.

```js
var number = "12.13";
var split = number.split(".");

console.log(split[0]);
console.log(split[1]);
```

Comment: And to convert split values to numbers, you could just map on `Number`, i.e. `i.split(".").map(Number)` --> `[12, 13]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

- If you have a number like `3.14` instead of `"3.14"` you first need to convert it to a string. calling `String(3.14)` or `(3.14).toString()` or `""+3.14`.
- Then call the method split() passing what you want to split the string by `split('.')`
- Then you will end up with an array of sub strings like `["3", "14"]`.
- Access each position of the array and convert it back to numbers if you want.
  `Number(arr[0])` or `parseInt(arr[0])` or `+arr[0]` or `arr[0]|0`

```js
var i = 12.13;

var arr = String(i).split('.'); //convert the number to string, and then split the string by `.` into an array
var part1 = parseInt(arr[0], 10); //get the first element and convert into a integer
var part2 = parseInt(arr[1], 10); //get the second element and convert into a integer

console.log(part1); // 12
console.log(part2); // 13
```

If you want a one-liner

```js
String("3.14").split(".").map(Number)
```

---

Alternatively you can also use RegExp. Use the index `array[1]` and `array[2]` instead

```js
"3.14".match(/(\d+)\.(\d+)/).map(Number) // [3.14, 3, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

Split by a dot (`.`) but not by a blank string. After splitting you get the list of number as an array. See the reference [**split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
var i = "12.13"
var t = i.split("."); 
console.log(t)
```

And now if you want to get the parts to two separate variable

```js
var i = "12.13"
var t = i.split(".").map(Number); // map() is to convert the string to number

var part1 = t[0]
var part2 = t[1]

console.log(part1, part2)
```